# Can't start pyspark shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[

`C:\Users\Asus>pyspark`

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJBdg.png

how to resolve this issue want to run it on my terminal,
tried running **bin\pyspark** no luck.

> After days of tweaking the environment variable reached to this solution still no luck, any form of suggestions would be appreciated